# SQLServer Encryption Of Data Channel From C#

Tags: c#, encryption

Can anyone give me pointers on how to achieve the above - I am familiar with the C# libraries and database connectivity but have never had to use a secure channel.

What do I need to do in C# and on the database side to force connections to always be encrypted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898) for details on how to do this.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly...

You do not need to change the connection object you are using???

You need to add a certificate to the sql server database and modify your connection string????

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to secure communication without SSL certs between a web server and SQL Server machine is to use IPSec.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302366.aspx